# How to tell sympy to keep exact numbers as exact in integrate?

Tags: sympy

When I typed

```
>python
> from sympy import *
> x=symbols('x')
> integrate(1/4/sin(1/3*x),x)
```

The output was

```
0.375*log(cos(0.333333333333333*x) - 1) - 0.375*log(cos(0.333333333333333*x) + 1)
```

What should one do to tell sympy not to convert exact input to floating point? I know I could type the following instead

```
integrate(S('1/4')/sin(S('1/3')*x),x)
```

And now the result is

```
 3*log(cos(x/3) - 1)/8 - 3*log(cos(x/3) + 1)/8
```

But I'd like to get this result, without having to wrap each number with `S('')` as in the above.

Is there an option or module one needs to import for this?

Using

```
>conda list sympy
sympy                     1.0                      py36_0
```

On linux.

Answer (score 3):

> without having to wrap each number with `S('')`

This can be avoided by wrapping the entire expression in `S('')`:

```
integrate(S('1/4/sin(1/3*x)'), x)
```

> tell sympy not to convert exact input to floating point

It's not SymPy who evaluates 1/3 as a floating point number; it's Python. In `sin(1/3*x)`, the division 1/3 occurs on Python level before SymPy objects such as `x` get involved.

---

Aside: with a more mathematically natural way of expressing the same formula,

```
integrate(1/(4*sin(x/3)), x)
```

one does not need `S()` at all, since there is no division of scalars here. Indeed, `1/(4*sin(x/3))` parses as

```
Mul(Rational(1, 4), Pow(sin(Mul(Rational(1, 3), Symbol('x'))), Integer(-1)))
```

while `1/4/sin(1/3*x)` parses as

```
Mul(Float('0.25', prec=15), Pow(sin(Mul(Float('0.33333333333333331', prec=15), Symbol('x'))), Integer(-1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `isympy -i` as your interpreter. This will start an interactive SymPy session where integers are automatically wrapped using `S`, so that you don't need to worry about dividing integers. But note that this only works interactively. If you want to write code using SymPy in a file, it is recommend to wrap divided integers with `S` or use `Rational`.

By the way, you can usually avoid this issue by writing your expression in such a way that you don't have `integer/integer`. For instance, instead of `1/4/sin(1/3*x)` you could write `1/(4*sin(x/3))` (or `1/sin(x/3)/4`). You only really need to use `S` when you have a rational number by itself, like `S(1)/2 + x`.